# Closed form for sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

I wonder whether there is a closed form for this sum
$$ S_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{4^k}{4^k+5^k}$$
The question asks to express the sum in terms of $n$ then to deduce the limit of $\dfrac{S_n}{n+1}$.
I tried to use the following sum as an auxiliary sum
$$T_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac{5^k}{4^k+5^k}$$ 
noticing that $S_n + T_n = n+1$.
Any thoughts about this ? thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to express the sum in terms of $n$, but I am a little confused. Don't we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{4^k}{4^k+5^k}\leq\sum_{k=0}^\infty(\frac45)^k=\frac1{1-\frac45}=5$ and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n+1}=0$?

Comment: Also, Wolfram Alpha gives a closed form involving the $q$-digamma function, which I've never heared of, and I doubt you have. What makes you think there is a closed form of the sum?

Comment: Thanks, the first part of the question in a paper (which I doubt is wrong) asks to express $S_n$ in terms of $n$ before computing the limit of the quotient $\dfrac{S_n}{n+1}$

Comment: @OussamaSarih, can you link to the paper, or reproduce *verbatim* what it says about expressing $S_n$? Given that the first three $S_n$'s are $1/2$, $17/18$, and $985/738$, I'd be a little surprised to see any kind of simple closed formula. (Even well written papers make occasional mistakes.)

Comment: It's a homework sheet in french for highschool, I'll post a screenshot as soon as I get from one from the students who asked me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by SmileyCraft, I cannot think of any simple closed form to express $S_n$.

My best guess is to use [Big $\mathcal{O}$ notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). As you thought, $S_n = n+1 - T_n$ then write $T_n = \sum_{k=0}^n u_k$ with $u_k = \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k}\underset{k\to\infty}{=}1 + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k$. Now $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k$ is a positive real sequence thus sommable in Big $\mathcal{O}$ notation.

This yields:
$$
S_n \underset{n\to \infty}{=} n+1 - \left[(n+1) + \mathcal{O}(1) \right] = \mathcal{O}(1)
$$

since $\sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^k \underset{n\to \infty}{=} \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Then $\frac{S_n}{n+1} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n+1})$.

Note that it is very similar and perfectly equivalent to what SmileyCraft does but it does give you an expression of $S_n$  (though trivial) depending on $n$.